# Proof for distances to a set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

> With a metric space $(X,d)$, prove that $|d_E(x)-d_E(y)|\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$.

In this context, $x \in X$, $d_E(x)=\inf\left\{d(x,z) : z \in E\right\}$, E is a subset of X.

I've already proved the statement without absolute values; I tried using contradiction and the definition of absolute value, but it didn't really lead anywhere.

Comment: What is $z$? Seems like something is missing.

Comment: Sorry, z is some point in E. I'll add a little more.

Comment: Maybe $d_E(x) = \inf \{ d(x,e):e \in E\}$?

Comment: Don't put conditions on $x$ inside the $\inf\{\}$ - it makes it look like $x$ varies in the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
d_E(x)\leq d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z) \quad \forall z\in E
$$
Thus,$d_E(x)-d(x,y)\leq d_E(y)\Rightarrow d_E(x)-d_E(y)\leq d(x,y)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. The last inequality holds since $d(.,.)\geq0$.

Similarly,
$$
d_E(y)\leq d(y,z)\leq d(y,x)+ d(x,z) \quad \forall z\in E
$$

So, $d_E(y)-d(y,x)\leq d_E(x)\Rightarrow -d(x,y)-d(y,z)\leq-d(y,x)\leq d_E(x)-d_E(y)$.Then argument follows at once from these two.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How did you go from $d_E(y)−d(y,x)≤d_E(x)$ to $−d(x,y)−d(y,z)≤−d(y,x)≤d_E(x)−d_E(y)$?

Comment: Since $d(x,y)+d(y,z)\geq d(y,x)$  multiplying $-1$ and combining with $-d(x,y)\geq d_E(x)-d_E(y)$ gives us the result. Hope this clarifies my jumps in those steps.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help

Comment: @RubberDucky: When an answer is helpful, you really ought to upvote it at least, and the best helpful answer should usually be accepted; see http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Sorry - I guess I haven't figured out everything on stack exchange yet. I did both things you suggested (I think).

Answer (score 1):

$$\vert d_E(x) - d_E(y) \vert \leq \max\{d_E(x),d_E(y)\} \leq \max\{d(x,z),d(y,z)\} \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z).$$

Here the last inequality uses the triangle inequality

Comment: Didn't end up using this argument, but I appreciate your help anyway